# SQL Where clause returns nothing - Beginner

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a table that has 3 fields, `ID`, `Name`, `Address`. (`Name` and `Address` are type String)

There are instances, where the `Address` is left `Null`. How do i write an SQL to get all address that are not `Null`.

My workings so far;

```
select * from Hotel where Address != NULL
```

Zero results were printed, after executing this command (even though there are such records stored in the DB). How should i alter the SQL ?

I am using MySQL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `IS NOT NULL` instead of `!= NULL`

```
select * from Hotel where Address IS NOT NULL
```

Check out [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Answer (score 10):

You need to use the SQL conditionals `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` instead of `!= NULL`.

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from Hotel where Address is not NULL
```

Nothing can be equal to null.

edit. I arrived too late :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM Hotel WHERE Address IS NOT null
```

Answer (score 2):

If the table is marked to allow null values use

```
select * from Hotel where Address IS NOT NULL
```

if there is a default to empty string then

```
select * from Hotel where Address != ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select * from Hotel where Address IS NOT NULL;
```